# ConnectionFailure when connecting to MongoHQ URI via Flask-PyMongo on httpd

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mod-wsgi, pymongo

I have a Flask app with a Mongo backend working perfectly in my local dev environment. I moved it to an AWS-hosted RHEL instance and got the Flask app working via httpd/mod_wsgi. However, connecting to a DB on MongoHQ continues to fail.

The code for the connection is this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = 'mongodb://myusername:mypasswd@myhost.mongohq.com:myport/mydb'
mongo = PyMongo(app)
```

A sample query:

```
@app.route('/books')
def books()
    all_books = mongo.db.listings.distinct("bookinfo")
    return all_books
```

The error message from Apache (edited for readability):

```
mod_wsgi (pid=5116, process='myProcess', application=''): Loading WSGI script '/route/to/myapp.wsgi'. 
mod_wsgi (pid=5116): Target WSGI script '/route/to/myapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module. 
mod_wsgi (pid=5116): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/route/to/myapp.wsgi'. 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/route/to/myapp.wsgi", line 10, in <module>
     from myApp import app as application   
File "/route/to/myapp.py", line 8, in <module>
     mongo = PyMongo(app)
File "/route/to/my/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask_pymongo/__init__.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.init_app(app, config_prefix)
File "/route/to/my/venv/python2.6/site-packages/flask_pymongo/__init__.py", line 230, in init_app
     cx = connection_cls(*args, **kwargs)
File "/route/to/my/venv/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 352, in __init__
     raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))
ConnectionFailure: could not connect to myhost.mongohq.com:myport: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

My thoughts/investigation:

1. The app runs fine when I remove the DB Connection: So it's not a
   mod_wsgi, Apache, or permissions issue?
2. I can connect to the mongo uri via the Mongo shell and Python shell but not through the app: So it's not a firewall issue?
3. MongoHQ's ultraresponsive customer service (seriously, they're awesome) believes it's an issue with the Flask-PyMongo driver, but I have no idea how to debug that.

Any help/hints/possibilities would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to use separate config variables from http://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#configuration like `MONGO_HOST`, `MONGO_PORT` etc?

Comment: Yes and it gives the same exact error message. I've also tried connecting using pymongo.MongoClient(x) where x is the mongo_uri string, but the same error.

Comment: Well, then it's pymongo problem but you've stated you can actually connect with pymongo in your question. Please correct it.

Comment: Apologies for that and corrected. I meant I'd connected using pymongo in the Python shell. Will continue to investigate the pymongo connection. Thanks!

Comment: Some other thoughts. Is SELinux enabled? Is user you use inside shell differs from user under which app is running?

Comment: SELinux was enabled (rookie mistake! I'd disabled the firewall but not SELinux) and disabling it helped. The app now runs with no error messages but I still can't return any results from mongodb queries. Possibly there's an error in my query code or httpd.conf. Will debug that now. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Finally debugged all of this. SELinux was the root of the issue, but adding a logger (thanks to a SO question and the wsgi documentation) helped me iron out where the queries were failing. I've pasted the logging code above. Thank you twil.

Answer (score 0):

SELinux was the root cause for this. I'd disabled the firewall but never turned off SELinux by editing the /etc/sysconfig/selinux file. After doing so, the app still had issues, but this logging code helped tremendously:

```
import logging
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='/var/www/myapp/flaskerror.log')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```